# Can I use a gerund after "stopping"?

Tags: verbs, gerunds

He turned his face toward the window **without stopping scrolling** on his smartphone.

Is it grammatically correct to use a gerund after the gerund form of the verb "to stop", which needs to be followed by a gerund in this case?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44078/two-consecutive-gerunds-ing-ing

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh, Good find!

Comment: @Wistful. I guess it does answer my question, although the example sentences used in that post don't include a negative. I'm still left with the possibility that the use of two consecutive gerunds after "without" might sound odd to a native English speaker, who perhaps might formulate the sentence in a different way. But maybe I'm just being overly paranoid.

Comment: The simple answer is no. The succession of two gerund-participials is excluded with certain verbs by what is known as the **'doubl-_ing_ constraint'**, which typically applies with a small sub-set of catenative verbs like "begin", "cease", "continue", "start", "stop".

Comment: @BillJ So, how would you phrase the sentence then? How about, "without ceasing to..."? Or, "without stopping THE scrolling on..."?