# Possessive case with gerunds in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds, possessives, exam-questions, grammaticality-in-context

As I was doing an exercise on transformation of sentences (from a Cambdridge exam), I came across a sentence that still puzzles me:

*Sam moved house only because he disliked commuting.* = *But for his ________ moved house.* (Fill the gap with 3-8 words and use **dislike**).

The correct answer is: *But for his dislike of commuting, Sam would not have moved house.* But now, forgetting about the constraints imposed by the exercise, would the following sentence be correct?

*But for his disliking commuting, Sam would not have moved house.*

I have recently learnt about the Possessive Case with gerunds, so I am not entirely sure about its correct use, but I do not understand why the above sentence could be incorrect. I have been told that it is not a proper answer because after "his" must come a noun, and therefore, "dislike" instead of "disliking", and that otherwise, it should be "But for him disliking commuting, ...". But even so, I still do not understand why the possessive can't be used with the gerund in my sentence.

I would be grateful if you could throw some light on whether my sentence is correct or not and why.

Comment: Do you mean *But for his disliking **of** commuting*?

Comment: No, I meant to use _disliking commuting_ as _taking time_ in "I appreciate your **taking time** to answer my question", for example, or like _disliking dogs_ in "This is the reason for your **disliking dogs**".

Comment: You mean using a gerund to modify another gerund, I never seen that. I know you can say "since you dislike commuting". I do not think natives construct compound names using two consecutive gerunds. However, "taking time" and "disliking doge" are gerund phrases. Lets wait for the native :)

Comment: I was referring to using the gerund as is explained here: [Using the Possessive Case with Gerunds](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/022205posscasegerunds.htm)

Comment: The link you provided says that you can use gerunds with possessives, but I could not see any possessive thing in **"disliking commuting"**. One can say **"disliking's commuting"**, but I think no one would understand them.

Comment: The possessive thing is in "But for **his** disliking commuting, ...", the use of "his" instead of "him".

Comment: I see your point, but please notice that you have "one" possessive pronoun, his, and two gerunds. Thus, [disliking commuting] is a compound noun or a noun phrase or gerund phrase or whatever (!) which I think it is wrong since I've never seen that a gerund modifies another gerund.

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you meant! I was thinking of the gerund "commuting" simply as a noun, so that it can act as any other noun does. Maybe this is what is wrong with my sentence, I don't know. If that's the case, let's wait for some feedback on the cases where gerunds can or can't go together!

Comment: @Cardinal The second gerund is the object of the first. "He dislikes commuting" → *his disliking commuting*.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you.I see your point. I mentioned above that I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*But for his disliking commuting* is formally OK.

A gerund is a noun and a verb **at the same time**. Inside the VP it may act as a verb—here, for instance, *disliking* takes an object, *commuting*—while externally it acts as a noun—here *disliking* acts as the object of the preposition *for*.

The subject of a gerund may be cast in either object or possessive case. Broadly, *him disliking* would be used in contexts where the gerund is "verbier", and *his disliking* in contexts where it is "nounier". In this particular instance the preposition gives *disliking* a very "nouny" feel, so *his* is better than *him*.

HOWEVER: the use of two gerunds back-to-back like that is jarring (linguists call it [*horror aequi*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/15380/32)), so the "correct" answer, with the full noun, is better.