# to continue or continuing

Tags: infinitives

*Dear President-elect, the Czech Republic as well as I personally look forward to working with you and your administration and **to continue** developing the close relations which our countries enjoy.*

Source: https://twitter.com/PREZIDENTmluvci

Don't you think that the verb "to continue" is used wrongly? Should it not be the correct form "continuing"?

Comment: "Continue" is one of a small number of verbs that cannot occur in the _ing_ form when its complement is in the same form. The succession of two _ing_ forms in "continuing developing" is not permitted by a rule called the 'doubl-_ing_ constraint'. You need "to continue developing" or "continuing to develop"; either will do.

Comment: This is actually a classic example of one of the rules for good English writing style.  If you have a "list" two or more items in the same sentence, you should use a parallel structure for each (*working* ... *continuing*). "Continue developing" has the right idea, but (if you have to use this phrase) "continuing to develop" is better style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, but you also need to recast *develop* to avoid the [*horror aequi*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/15380/32) of *continuing developing*:

```
 look forward to working    with you and your administration 
          and to continuing to develop the close relations which our countries enjoy
```

But it's still trying to cram too much into one clause.

Answer (score 0):

It could be "...to continue developing" or "and continuing to develop..." it would not sound correct to have an -Ing verb after the other unless it is in a list like biking, developing,etc.