# Think of start doing something

Tags: word-usage

> Whenever I **think of start doing something**, the first thing comes to my mind is "I lack resources"

Is it OK to say ***"think of start doing something"***? Because I can't find any result for that in Google.

All I find is, *"think of"* followed by object pronouns *(Eg. you)* or verb+ing form words *(Eg. starting, doing)*. But I can't cite any *"think of start doing"* example.

This question may look trivial, but please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not okay. The grammar is actually wrong. If it's a verb that comes after the phrasal verb *to think of*, you should follow this pattern:

```
to think of doing something
```

That *something* can be anything you want. Even another *doing something* if the verb with which it's used allows you to employ another "ing" form. Thus, you can certainly say *think of doing doing something* if you're otherwise not breaking any other grammar rules. But, in this case, I'd go with Khan's suggestion and say that it probably does sound a little bit better to say *starting to do something* rather than *starting doing something*:

> Whenever I **think of starting to do something**, the first thing that comes to my mind is "I lack resources".

Here's a simple rule of thumb to remember: in general, you can't use verbs after prepositions. It has to be either a noun (or a noun phrase) or a gerund (the "ing" form of a verb which allows verbs to function as nouns). To better illustrate the point that I'm trying to make, take a look at these examples:

> You can significantly improve your English-speaking skills through **listening**. [gerund]
>
> You can significantly improve your English-speaking skills through **prolonged exposure to authentic English**. [noun phrase]
>
> You can significantly improve your English-speaking skills through **listen**. [verb - WRONG]

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever I think of start doing something... [**incorrect**]

It's **not** grammatical; you use an -ing form after the phrase "think of". Also, you don't use an -ing form after starting and beginning. So it's incorrect to say:

> Whenever I think of starting doing something... [**incorrect**]

Instead, you can use a to-infinitive after starting as follows:

> Whenever I think of starting to do something... [**correct**]

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, but I don't think **starting doing something** is incorrect: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15378/should-we-always-use-verb-ing-structure-after-the-verb-start

Comment: See https://www.thefreedictionary.com/start and https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+starting+to+do%2C+I+am+starting+doing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20am%20starting%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Right, **starting to do** is a lot more common than **starting doing**: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=starting+to+do%2Cstarting+doing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstarting%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstarting%20doing%3B%2Cc0 But my point is that it certainly seems like people do occasionally say **starting doing** too

Comment: "Starting doing" grates on my ears, and the answer you link to points out that it's grammatical but rare and generally avoided. "started doing" is fine; "starting doing" doesn't sound right. Even some of the results from your ngram look like typos or "misspeaks" to me, for example: _After the 1993 reunion in San Antonio, we starting doing a newsletter and then changed it to a journal._ I think that should be "started doing".